# Global Configuration page not showing correctly

Tags: global-configuration

I'm running Joomla 3.4.8 and the Global Configuration page is showing without any layout or buttons. I have looked at the following:

forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=624&t=690980

but it doesn't seem to apply with 3.4.x.

I also removed the last two extensions that were added, JCE and Phocagallery but that did not correct the issue.

No other pages are being rendered incorrectly.

I would appreciate any suggestions. -ch

Comment: Try setting `$error_reporting` in your **configuration.php** to `development`, then try again. Report any errors back here

Comment: changed $error_reporting to 'development'. When I try to go to the login screen, I get a 500 error. I can't login.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225027/500-internal-server-error-at-back-end-joomla) and [this documentation article](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/troubleshooter/prbasicts.html)

Comment: Hello, after set `$error_reporting` to `development` in the configuration file please place this line into your administrator index.php `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Then post the error message here to see what we can do.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem in two sites: **Global Configuration page is showing without any layout or buttons.**

That worked for me:

A **bclass.php** file placed in:
PATH_TO_JOOMLA_SITE/libraries/joomla/database/driver

After **removing that file**, the Global Configuration page went back to normal.
Apparently this was a file from when the site is hacked.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the Joomla cache and your local browser cache can often fix this type of issue especially after updating from Joomla 2.5.8 to 3.x or after moving the website from one host to another.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

You need to re-install joomla version 3.4.8. Do this from your website folder on your web hosting server. NOT from Joomla back end where you install extension.

1. Login to your hosting server admin panel.
2. Locate "library" folder in your website folder and rename it to library-x. You can delete library-x later.
3. Upload Joomla_3.4.8-Stable-Full_Package.zip to your website folder on your hosting server.
4. Extract Joomla_3.4.8-Stable-Full_Package.zip to your website folder.

This will fix the problem. It did for mine.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution suggestion on another website: there was a suggestion to remove bclass.php in libraries / joomla / database / driver. but I didn't have that file. In this case, I opened the driver folder in my old web site backup, I opened the current driver folder in front of it, an extra pgsql.php file appeared. When I disabled it, I checked the site and GENERAL CONFIGURATION worked. There was no problem on the website. :) (take a backup)

Answer (score 0):

I rename PATH_TO_JOOMLA_SITE/libraries/joomla/database/driver pgsql.php to pgsql-removed.php and configs works for me!

Comment: Thank you for contributing Daniel.  Please take our [tour].